# Could not open property database

Tags: apache2

I am using Windows XP , i want to have a repository , so i created it using Apache Server

Inside my Apache server , why i am getting this error ??

I have used this to  create my repository under httpd-dav.conf

Alias /sites "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/sites"

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/sites">
    Dav On

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName DAV-upload

    Options Indexes

    AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/user.passwd"
    AuthDigestProvider file

    # Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
    # to the admin user.
    <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
        require user admin
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Sat Oct 01 15:44:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
```

please tell me how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 2):

I am using Window 2008. 
What I found was that the default entry for the  `DavLockDB`  in the \conf\extra folder was:

/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/var/DavLock

However, there was no `var` directory created under the Windows install.

Creating the `var` directory seemed to solve it.